# SharePoint Email alert

Tags: sharepoint, alert

I have subscribed a particular item from a list using the following code. This will send the email alert for the filtered items only. But I expect an email alert at each time when the same type of item is added in list. How can I achieve this functionality?

```
{
    SPAlert newAlert = oUser.Alerts.Add();
    newAlert.Title = mylistitem.Title;
    newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item;
    newAlert.Item = mylistitem;
    SPListItem myListItem = oWeb.Lists[_PAGES].Items.GetItemById(mylistitem.ID);
    newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
    newAlert.Update(true);
    newAlert = null;
}
oWeb.Lists[_PAGES].Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list alert template that filters for your type and upload to the webservice alerttemplate collection.
2. Create a list alert with that alerttemplate and attach it to your list.

Answer (score 0):

In **SPAlert** you have property called Filter, there you can add a Caml Query to specified ContentType.

```
<Query><Contains> <FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>ContentTypeName</Value> </Contains></Query>
```

Remember that you have to set **Value** type to **Text** otherwise you get parse error.